# Convert date from milliseconds to ISODate object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, type-conversion, aggregation-framework

I am trying to aggregate records in a MongoDB collection by hour and need to convert date stored as timestamp (milliseconds) to ISODate so that I can use aggregate framework's built-in date operators ($hour, $month, etc.)

Records are stored as

```
{ 
"data" : { "UserId" : "abc", "ProjId" : "xyz"}, 
"time" : NumberLong("1395140780706"),
"_id" : ObjectId("532828ac338ed9c33aa8eca7") 
}
```

I am trying to use an aggregate query of following type:

```
db.events.aggregate(
    { 
       $match : { 
         "time" : { $gte : 1395186209804, $lte : 1395192902825 } 
       } 
    }, 
    { 
       $project : {
         _id : "$_id", 
         dt : {$concat : (Date("$time")).toString()} // need to project as ISODate
       } 
    },
    // process records further in $project or $group clause
)
```

which produces results of the form:

```
{
    "result" : [
        { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5328da21fd207d9c3567d3ec"), 
            "dt" : "Fri Mar 21 2014 17:35:46 GMT-0400 (EDT)" 
        }, 
        { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("5328da21fd207d9c3567d3ed"), 
            "dt" : "Fri Mar 21 2014 17:35:46 GMT-0400 (EDT)" 
        }, 
            ... 
}
```

I want to extract hour, day, month, and year from the date but since time is projected forward as string I am unable to use aggregate framework's built-in date operators ($hour, etc.).

How can I convert time from milliseconds to ISO date to do sometime like the following:

```
db.events.aggregate(
    {
        $match : { 
            "time" : { $gte : 1395186209804, $lte : 1395192902825 } 
        }
    },
    {
        $project : {
            _id : "$_id",
            dt : <ISO date from "$time">
        }
    },
    { 
        $project : {
            _id : "$_id",
            date : { 
                hour : {$hour : "$dt"} 
            }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: You should consider map/reduce in the place of aggregate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume there's no way to do it. Because aggregation framework is written in native code. not making use of the V8 engine. Thus everything of JavaScript is not gonna work within the framework (And that's also why aggregation framework runs much faster).
Map/Reduce is a way to work this out, but aggregation framework definitely got much better performance.

About Map/Reduce performance, read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678631/map-reduce-performance-in-mongodb-2-2-and-2-4).

Another way to work it out would be get a "raw" result from aggregation framework, put it into an JSON array. Then do the conversion by running JavaScript. Sort of like:

```
var results = db.events.aggregate(...);
reasult.forEach(function(data) {
    data.date = new Date(data.dateInMillionSeconds);
    // date is now stored in the "date" property
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will give the part-Mongo/part-JS solution a try.

Comment: This hasn't been correct for some time; see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27828951/1259510).

Answer (score 31):

Actually, it is possible, the trick is to add your milliseconds time to a zero-milliseconds Date() object using syntax similar to:

```
dt : {$add: [new Date(0), "$time"]}
```

I modified your aggregation from above to produce the result:

```
db.events.aggregate(
    {
        $project : {
            _id : "$_id",
            dt : {$add: [new Date(0), "$time"]}
        }
    },
    { 
        $project : {
            _id : "$_id",
            date : { 
                hour : {$hour : "$dt"} 
            }
        }
    }
);
```

The result is (with one entry of your sample data):

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("532828ac338ed9c33aa8eca7"),
      "date": {
        "hour": 11
      }
    }
  ],
  "ok": 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To return a valid BSON date all you need is a little date "maths" using the [`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) operator. You need to add `new Date(0)` to the timestamp. The `new Date(0)` represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970) and is a shorthand for `new Date("1970-01-01")`.

```
db.events.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "time": { "$gte" : 1395136209804, "$lte" : 1395192902825 } } },
    { "$project": { 
        "hour": { "$hour": { "$add": [ new Date(0), "$time" ] } }, 
        "day": { "$dayOfMonth":  { "$add": [ new Date(0), "$time" ] } },
        "month": { "$month": { "$add": [ new Date(0), "$time" ] } },
        "year": { "$year":  { "$add": [ new Date(0), "$time" ] } } 
    }} 
])
```

Which yields:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("532828ac338ed9c33aa8eca7"),
    "hour" : 11,
    "day" : 18,
    "month" : 3,
    "year" : 2014
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting `Mongo 4.0`, there is a new [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/#exp._S_toDate) aggregation operator which can convert from various types to a date (in this case from a long):

```
// { time: NumberLong("1395140780706") }
db.collection.aggregate({ $set: { time: { $toDate: "$time" } } })
// { time: ISODate("2014-03-18T11:06:20.706Z") }
```

And to get the hour out of it:

```
// { time: NumberLong("1395140780706") }
db.collection.aggregate({ $project: { hour: { $hour: { $toDate: "$time" } } } })
// { hour: 11 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> use this if `{$add: [new Date(0), "$time"]`} function returning `string type` not an `ISO date type`

I use all of that option but still fail, because my new date from `$project` return a `string type` like `'2000-11-2:xxxxxxx'` not `date type` like `ISO('2000-11-2:xxxxxxx')` for anyone who have same problem with me use this.

```
db.events.aggregate(
    {
        $project : {
            _id : "$_id",
            dt : {$add: [new Date(0), "$time"]}
        }
    },
    { 
        $project : {
            _id : "$_id",
            "year": { $substr: [ "$dt", 0, 4 ] },
            "month": { $substr: [ "$dt", 5, 2] },
            "day": { $substr: [ "$dt", 8, 2 ] }
        }
    }
);
```

the result will be

```
 { _id: '59f940eaea87453b30f42cf5',
    year: '2017',
    month: '07',
    day: '04' 
},
```

you can get hours or minute if you want depending on which `string` you want to `subset`, then you can `group` that again according to same date,month or year